# Trash Bin in Unity launcher shows full even when empty

Tags: unity, trash

I'm having a weird problem where my Trash Bin in Unity launcher is showing full when its not. Usually it wouldn't bother me but its been happening so often lately its getting annoying. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this might be caused by a bug associated with trashing items on an external hard drive. I've filed a bug report here: http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1076121 . If you experience the same behavior, please click on the green line "This bug affects ... users. Does it affect you?" -> "Yes, it affects me too."

Comment: Indeed. I plugged in my USB stick, trash showed files now, deleted them, and trash icon is empty again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just delete the files, and if the bin is still full I would open a Terminal (`Ctrl`-`Alt`-`T`), type "`xkill`" and press enter. This will change the mouse pointer into an X. Hover the mouse over the Unity Dashboard and press the left mouse button. This will kill the dashboard, and one second later it will come back.

EDIT: The xkill approach will kill the session and the apps running in it and you'll have to login again. It does result in an empty trashcan icon though. (Tested under 14.04): It appears this is a long standing bug with many duplicates see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-applets/+bug/269441

Comment: Thanks that helped I also found that I could jusr run `unity --replace`via HUD and it reloads the panel.

Comment: "unity --replace" seems like it's broken too, it kills my whole session and kicks me back to the login screen.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 it doesn't come back.......

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. Files that were deleted from a USB drive were causing the Trash to appear full even though it was empty. As soon as I emptied the trash with the USB drive mounted, the trash was cleared.

Comment: What if you don't have that USB drive at hand?

Answer (score 3):

The trash on the desktop tries to sum up all the trashes current user can access.

Each disk, each drive, has got its own trash, sort of speaking.

So (desktop) trash staying full after the usb stick is unplugged means :

- trash has not been emptied while usb stick was plugged in,
- deleted files on that usb stick are still present, they've just been moved to the "onboard" .trash folder but not actually deleted.

If that happens just plug in back that usb stick, or external drive, and deleted files will appear again inside the (desktop) trash. Now empty that trash and files from all "connected" trashes will be actually deleted.

It's not a bug. It's just how trashes work under linux-ubuntu.

Comment: I can assure you that in the case of multiple drives trash on the desktop does not "sum up all the trashes the current user can access"

Comment: Well… that surprises me and think it's unexpected. It _should_ sum up. It may be a more general right/permission problem ???

Comment: It could be.  I've experienced the issue with a 3 TB drive formatted with GPT. Im not sure if that's relevant but the failure to address files on that internal drive in the trash can led me to post this question. http://askubuntu.com/questions/698058/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-trash-cans-for-seperate-partitions-in-the-unity/705076#705076 Perhaps I misidentified the problem. However I clearly have rights to trash files there as well as remove them. Curious.

Answer (score 2):

Found that deleting files from ext-HDD causes the trash bin to be full even though its not. The solution is to move the files you want to delete from external to trash-bin than empty. Or log out and log back in

Comment: Is this the solution instead?  Or a comment to your original post?

Comment: I can confirm the logout login workaround works.  I'm considering using trash-cli instead. Too bad I can't remove the can from the launcher...