# Is it possible to have multiple trash cans for separate partitions in the unity launcher?

Tags: nautilus, launcher, delete, trash

I have a separate drive mounted at `/srv`. If I create a `/srv/.Trash` folder files on that drive are successfully moved to a `/srv/.Trash/1000` upon move to trash. If I don't have a `/srv/.Trash` folder I can create a `/srv/.Trash-1000` folder which also works as expected. Since the system wants to store trash on the same partition from whence it came how can I create multiple trashcans so that I can empty the trash from a drive that's not root or home mounted? Any ideas? I've seen several related questions like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536598/nautilus-trash-doesnt-show-deleted-files-on-other-partitions) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57043/after-deleting-files-i-do-not-get-any-more-space-on-my-hard-drive-and-files-are?rq=1) but I can't find anything that addresses this use case. I do not want the files moved to a different drive just to put them in the trash can, I'd just like to be able to easily manage the trash on this separate drive.

Edit: I tried [Possible to have 2 unity launchers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/45301/possible-to-have-2-unity-launchers?lq=1) which appeared to raise the possibility of using Avant Window Navigator to accomplish a second trash can, possibly configurable via a gconf key as mentioned in post 5 [here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/awn-extras/+bug/194431) Unfortunately Although it seems AWN is back in development, it appears that there isn't anything available for my current 14.04 installation.

Comment: You could create a symlink to the trash folders in your desktop: `ln -s /path/to/external/drive/trashcan $HOME/Desktop`.

Comment: @EduardoCola True, but I don't see how this would be an improvement over a shortcut in Nautilus. I'm leaning toward the CLI solution but have to complete further testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the root cause of this problem was mounting to a system_internal mount path which resulted in Trash folders that didn't have the sticky bit set. A Simple solution is to issue the command `chmod -t /mount/point/.TrashFolder` adjusting your path and folder name to match your circumstances.

Source:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516031/67643

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround** - Create a shortcut in Nautilus to the Trash folder in the drive desired in a new tab as seen below and manually deleting the folders files and info. I sincerely hope that someone can come up with a better solution while although this is a functional solution it is less than ideal.
[image: Trash]

**A better alternative** is to use the [trash-cli package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=trash-cli&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) such as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468721/how-can-i-empty-the-trash-using-terminal) which can be installed with `sudo apt-get install trash-cli` and empties all of a users trash with the command `trash-empty`

This could be dressed up with bells and whistles as described in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/335964/empty-trash-sound-event/396966#396966)